# Using export_fig() with transparency in images

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm using the `export_fig()` function (available [here](https://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig)) to generate raster graphics of figures produced in MATLAB.

Using the argument `'-zbuffer'`, I am able to produce graphics of figures that contain images placed on the plot using the `image()` command. However, any transparency in the images is lost, and replaced by black. The figures I produce are made of multiple image elements layered on top of one another, with transparency to each of the `image()`s used, so that the others can be seen underneath.

Does anyone know how to use `export_fig()` with `image()`s that contain transparency?

n.b. The `'-transparent'` argument doesn't achieve this.

Comment: "The `'-transparent'` argument doesn't achieve this." - surely this makes it a bug in `export_fig` then?  Have you tried contacting the author?  Also, have you done this (from the link you gave): "use the -transparent option, **and set the axes 'Color' property to 'none' where desired**"?

Comment: The `'-transparent'` argument isn't designed for this - it is for a completely different function. Adding this argument removes the background of figures and has nothing to do with transparency in images embedded in the figure. I am not trying to remove the axes. I am trying to make images stacked on top of one another retain their alpha channels.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood.  I thought when you said "transparency in the images is lost" you were referring to the output images.

Comment: I would look for some way to flatten the images before handing to export_fig

Comment: The reason for sending to export_fig is that it vectorises my plots, thus improving output quality. Raster images are still preserved though - except the transparency is lost :(

Comment: Plots are only vectorized if you use the `-painters` renderer. However, this doesn't support transparency - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you read MATLAB's notes on the [properties of different renderers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/changing-a-figures-settings.html?s_tid=doc_12b#f3-102410), you'll see that OpenGL is the only renderer to support transparent patch objects. So you need to use the `-opengl` option, not the `-zbuffer` option, in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the -opengl renderer.

Example : *export_fig( . ,'-opengl')*

I looked at the function. And the comment section of the function has the following description :

"The choice of renderer (opengl, zbuffer or painters) has a large impact
 on the quality of output. Whilst the default value (opengl for bitmaps,
 painters for vector formats) generally gives good results, if you aren't
 satisfied then try another renderer.

Notes:

1) For vector formats (eps, pdf), only painters generates vector graphics.

**2) For bitmaps, only opengl can render transparent patch objects correctly.**

3) For bitmaps,  only painters will correctly scale line dash and dot lengths when magnifying or anti-aliasing.

4) Fonts may be substitued with Courier when using painters."

Hope it helps.